# Series that avoids a given conditioning

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

A number n is *evil* if:

- It is an integer multiple of 6, 13, or 101, or
- It is an integer multiple of 3 but not of 9, or
- It contains the contiguous digit sequences "6", "13", "101" or "31".

A number n is *bad* if:

- It is evil, or
- The sum of its digits is evil, or
- N mod 30 is evil.

A number n is *good* if it is not bad.

A number n is *safe* if n, n+1, and n-1 are good.

Question: Is there any formula f(n) such that, for all integers n, if n is good then f(n) is good (and f(n) > n so that a series is created) ? How about g(n) such that, for all integers n, if n is safe then g(n) is safe? And is it possible to write these formulae without using any bad constants?

Comment: The trivial functions $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = n$ come to mind.

Comment: @Hrodelbert Fair point. Corrected question.

Comment: If you have any infinite sequence of good numbers, then just take $f(n)$ to be the smallest number in that sequence greater than $n$. (Perhaps this is reducing to the problem you're trying to solve in the first place!) Same with safe numbers. I note that powers of $10$ are always good, as are $10^n+1$ numbers.

Comment: $10^2 + 1 = 101$ and is evil.